# How to load a peer list file?

Tags: bitcoind, peer-discovery

According to [this page](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Satoshi_Client_Node_Discovery),

> The client will automatically read a file named "addr.txt" in the
>   bitcoin data directory and will add any addresses it finds in there as
>   node addresses.

However, I can't find any point in the source code where this file is actually read, and I don't know how to verify all the peers known by my node.

Is the "addr.txt" file actually read by bitcoind? 
How can I check if the addresses are actually loaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature is no longer present in Bitcoin Core.  It was [removed](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/commit/74567f7ef1b0c550523267c77ad3f8f1d2831c40) in 2011.

You can get the same effect by adding multiple `addnode=` lines to your bitcoin.conf.